# Program won't compiile

Tags: c

I am currently doing this program  that takes 2 value and an expressions and simple uses if else statements, when I go to run, it give me a exception thrown, here is the code, I am using MVS19, I think the code is correct but I have been searching and can't seem to find the right answer on why is not working

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 main(void)
{
    float value1, value2;
    char operator;

    printf("Type in your expressions.\n");
    scanf_s("%f %c %f", &value1, &operator, &value2);

    if (operator == '+')
        printf("%.2f\n", value1 + value2);
    else if (operator == '-')
        printf("%.2f\n", value1 - value2);
    else if (operator == '*')
        printf("%.2f\n", value1 * value2);
    else if (operator == '/')
        if (value2 == 0)
            printf("Division by zero.\n");
        else
            printf("%.2f\n", value1 / value2);
    else
        printf("Unknown operator.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

here is the warning that I am getting

```
Warning C4477   'scanf_s' : format string '%c' requires an argument of type 'unsigned int', but variadic argument 3 has type 'float *'  

Warning C4473   'scanf_s' : not enough arguments passed for format string
```

Comment: What is the exception ? Have you tried any debug to see how far it gets and perhaps what the input you read was ?

Comment: Not the root cause of your bug and I know you are in C, but `operator` is a keyword in C++.  Probably not a good name for a variable.

Comment: I have posted the warning, I have change the variable name and that did not do it, I tried to debug as well, as soon as I start typing in the console and press enter to summit the numbers I want calculated it gives me the exeption

Answer (score 1):

The warning message is pretty precise. You are using `scanf_s` as if it was `scanf`.

`scanf_s` takes an additional argument for `%c` specifiers indicating the size of the array that the passed `char*` refers to. This argument should have type `rsize_t`:

```
scanf_s("%f %c %f", &value1, &operator, (rsize_t)1, &value2);
```

or with the usual `scanf`:

```
scanf("%f %c %f", &value1, &operator, &value2);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019 says the size parameter is of type `unsigned`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am basing the `rsize_t` on the specification in the C18 Annex K, not the MS version. I would guess that MS just defines `rsize_t` to be `unsigned` to match the specification?

Comment: Great!, the `(rsize_t)1` worked fine, I will need to do some research on that so I can learn it, its new to me. this MS version does not seem to like `scanf`, when I first started using it I always get this error C4996 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.